# A card is dealt from a complete standard deck of $52$ playing cards (no jokers)

Tags: probability

A card is dealt from a complete standard deck of $52$ playing cards (no jokers). Use probability rules (when appropriate) to find the probability that the card is as stated. Count an ace as high only. Enter your answers as fractions.

(a) above an $8$

= $24/52$

(b) below a jack

= $36/52$

(c) both above an $8$ and below a jack

= $8/52$

(d) either above an $8$ or below a jack

= $52/52$

I think that there is an error in my answer in part (d) and/or maybe other parts so please state any errors so I can correct my answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

Your (d) answer of $52/52$ is wrong strictly speaking.  The English word "or", as in "A or B", is true only when exactly one of A,B is true but not both.  In my opinion, it is one of the most abused words in the English language.  So to be above an $8$ or below a jack means it would have to be any of : $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, J, Q, K, A$ so that would be $44/52$.  It is the complement of (c).  An easy way to see this is as follows:

Above an 8 are $9, 10, J, Q, K, A$.
Below a jack are $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10$

Now remove anything that is in both lines above in $bold$ cuz we don't want the intersection of them (specifically $9, 10$) since that is the and portion.

Have you ever heard anyone while speaking say "A or B or both" (another form is "A and or B")?  That is because they are taking away ambiguity by doing that meaning that the "A or B" subexpression is an exclusive or, meaning not both of A and B.

The "safest" thing to do is ask the person who stated "A or B" what they really meant (either inclusive or exclusive) and then answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I think <s>all of them are correct</s>. About your concerns with part d) the probability of either above an 8 (from 8 to ace) or below a jack (from 2 to jack) <s>covers all de deck as only one statement, not both, has to be true for the proposition to be true. This means that any card in the deck satisfies this condition, resulting in a $52/52$ probability.</s>

Edit: As David pointed out in a comment, this answer is only valid when the ***either A or B*** in the question is an inclusive **or** which, after revising your question, and because of the emphasise on the ***either***, does not seem to be the case as the general formulation for 'either A or B' is **normally** an exclusive **or** (**xor** in the table below). This means the proposition in question d) is true when A is true or B is true,   . Below is the Truth table for exclusive **or** (***xor***) and inclusive **or**:

[image]

The cases which satisfy question d) are the ones in the fourth column (exclusive **or**) second and third rows.

However, the exclusive **or** it is not always properly used. Consider someone asking the question: ***Is it either raining in Utah (A) or Illinois (B)?*** In this case the expected answer is true if A, B or both statetments are true which is why I think the context in which we are talking should be clear enough to distinguish between bot **or** and **xor**. But as a rule of thumb, **the explicit use of either means an exclusive or**.

So take then a look at David's answer to see what's really going on with the cards.

Comment: Hadn't really thought while answering about inclusive or exclusive **or**. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Someone could just ask "Is it raining in Utah and or Illinois" to mean inclusive or.

Comment: Also your statement (not statements) has the word either so why would you consider A or B to include A and B in that case?  That is contradictory.

Comment: Because one thing is what the sentence properly means and another thing is what the person asking is referring to.